# Copy text from a website, then rename files with it

Tags: batch-file

I have folder after folder of TV seasons, all files have horribly ugly names. I have used a file renmaing program to rename them in a tidy uniform format, eg "The Simpsons (S05E03) - ".

Now what I usually do is open Wikipedia, go to the shows List Of Episodes page, copy each episode name and paste it to the end of each file name. Very time consuming.

I would like run a batch file that copies each episode name I guess into a new line in a text file, then use the text file to extract the names then append to each filename. I suppose I would have to manually open the web page and scroll so the information started a specific number of lines from the top of the browser (the same each time), the get string at the coordinates containing each episode name? To start..

UPDATE:

I have sorted the first part, getting a text file of episode names. I just copied the entire table from Wikipedia, pasted into Word, then created a macro that formatted the table until only the epsiode names remained, then saved them to a new text file on the desktop, then closed Word.
So now I just have to write a batch file that appends each video file name with each line for the text file.. Is this possible?

Comment: is there is reason you want this to be a batch file, and not, say, Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it.

User "foxidrive" from dostips.com suggested this code:

```
@echo off
 :: creates file2.tmp from DIR and appends the information from file1.tmp onto the filenames
 :: designed to rename files and add info onto the end of the filename
 setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
 del undo.bat renfile.bat 2>nul

dir /b /a-d |find /v /i "%~nx0" |find /v /i ".tmp" >file2.tmp
 < file1.tmp (
 for /F "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("file2.tmp") do (
 set File2Line=
 set /P File2Line=
 set "File1Line=%%~na" & set "ext=%%~xa"
 setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion 
echo(ren "!File1Line!!ext!" "!File1Line!!File2Line!!ext!"
 echo(ren "!File1Line!!File2Line!!ext!" "!File1Line!!ext!">>undo.bat
 endlocal
 )
 ) >renfiles.bat
 call renfiles.bat
 del renfiles.bat
 del file2.tmp
```

This expects that in the current folder are 
A) the files which need text added to the end of the filename
B) plus file1.tmp which contains the text to be appended to each filename - in the correct order as the filenames files are sorted.
C) this batch file